# Creating easy classification visual tool (with Shiny)

Tags: classification, shiny

I have a model that predicts, based on multiple variables like income and marital status, whether a person is credit worthy (yes/no).

My question is whether it is possible to create a visual tool where you enter the value of each of the variables and then the tool gives you a YES or NO if it predicts this person is credit worthy.

I have seen something like this before and I think it was made with Shiny. However, I cannot find it anymore.

Any help or tips would be very appreciated!

Bert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code a function mymodel(a,b,c,d....) where a:d are your variables, and it returns TRUE or FALSE based on credit worthiness.

In your UI, use the widgets found here: http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson3/ to pass values to the input object.

Then, you can use:

```
shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {

    output$text1 <- renderText({ 
      if(mymodel(input$widget1,input$widget2,...)) {
          "Credit-Worthy"
      } else {
          "Not Credit-Worthy"
      }

    })

  }
)
```

Make sure in your UI, you then pass:

```
mainPanel(
      textOutput("text1")
    )
```

As found in http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson4/

This will give you a text output of a individuals credit-worthiness. If you want to have other visual effects, you can use the same if statement above to pass different themes/images/etc.. to output.